# Why CSS in the document body adversely impacts rendering performance?

Tags: css, performance

Google Chrome Audits says that "CSS in the document body adversely impacts rendering performance", but why?

If it's on the beginning of the body document, it will be loaded before the elements, right? So it's no like loading an a element and later change it's style, right?

Comment: Because "information about the current document, such as its title, keywords that may be useful to search engines, and other data that is not considered document content"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because most browsers are caching CSS as long as the CSS is in an external file and not in the `<style></style>` of the html.
So it will render faster the next time you will display the page.
But maybe there is more to know about this.